# Mostrar campo float em formato de moeda utilizando filters no AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou trabalhando com o AngularJS e para mostrar ao usuário um campo usando uma vírgula, eu infelizmente sou obrigado a fazer um `replace` no ponto.

Gostaria de saber se existe algum `filter` ou `directive` que me resolva o caso. No meu código, preciso que um campo `float` continue assim para que possa ser enviado ao `webservice`, mas para o usuário, um campo monetário é separado por vírgula e não por ponto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mais especificamente:

```
{{ Valor | currency:'BRL':2 }}
```

Para trazer a vírgula, altere seu app.module também:

```
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

.
.
.
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
      ...
      { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "pt-BR" },
      ...
  ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: excelente, ja nem lembrava dessa questão. um detalhe é que a pergunta era sobre o AngularJS não o Angular 2 (^4.0) mas como já estou trabalhando no 4.0 acabou me ajudando sem querer rsrs

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer a formatação diretamente na exibição, sem precisar manipular o valor através de um `filter` ou `directive` customizado. Exemplo:

```
$scope.meuValor = 10.3

<p>Valor: {{meuValor | currency}}</p>
```

Caso não seja feito a conversão automática (adicionado o R$), você ainda pode definir as opções de exibição, conforme a [documentação aqui](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngLocale/angular-locale_pt-br.js), como a sigla monetária e quantidade de casas após a virgula.

```
{{campo | currency:sigla:casas}}
{{campo | currency:'R$':2}}
```

Veja um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/gwxvu921/

---

#### Editado:

Havia esquecido do `.` na separação da casa decimal. Isso pode ser resolvido com o uso de um arquivo `locale`, como este: https://github.com/renato/bower-angular-locale-pt-br/blob/master/angular-locale_pt-br.js

Apenas faça o load desse arquivo na index, ou como achar melhor. Eu, por exemplo, faço concatenação dele com outros arquivos de funções montando um módulo que carrego como dependência do `module` principal.

Comment: um campo monetário é formado por um conjunto de 2 casas separadas por uma vírgula. já tinha visto na documentação do angular sobre o filter `currency`e sei como o mesmo trabalha mas, ele não formata com vírgulas.

Comment: @LeandroLUK Editei a resposta, acredito que seu problema será resolvido.

Comment: fantástico cara, não sabia que tinha como modificar o formato dos campos utilizando algo como esse link...

Comment: Na verdade, como você pode ver no arquivo, ele serve não só para a questão monetária, mas para diversas outras áreas, como data, horário, nomes comuns, etc.. Inclusive já vi alguns `locale` particulares com outras configurações, mas também depende do suporte. Mas com isso você já tem um bom caminho.